# \usepackage]{listings} - Overfull \box problem - Smaller characters/font?

Tags: listings

I am using this LaTeX code to implement some Python code in my LaTeX generated pdf document. I am using `\lstdefinestyle` because I have multiple styles for different code that I want to implement in the same file.

```
\lstdefinestyle{numbers} {numbers=left, stepnumber=1, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=8pt}
\lstdefinestyle{MyFrame}{backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},frame=shadowbox}

\lstdefinestyle{Python}{language=Python,
        frame=lines,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, 
        keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
        commentstyle=\color{comments},
        stringstyle=\color{red},
        showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\color{green},
        procnamekeys={def,class}}
```

I am implementing in this way:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Python]
   print 'here the code'
\end{lstlisting}
```

The problem is that the code is going to give me an *`Overfull \hbox`* error when I compile the LateX code.

I wrote the code keeping an eye on the "gray line" on the right in my Python editor (Spyder):

[image: Code Example]

Unfortunately many code lines that don't go above the grey line that you can see in the picture (which I tought was a mark to show where to stop writing) will not fit in LaTeX.

Is there anything that I can do to resize the code so that I don't get this result:

[image: LaTex Example]

I would like the text to stay all inside the red line when it stays inside the gray line in Spyder. If I am asking too much I would like a solution to scale down the code so that it can enter in the box. Maybe there is something in lstlisting that I can use to resize the code?

Re-writing the programs is not a solution :D.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I don't know of any automated solution for your problem. What I would do is choose a font for my listings and stick with it, then adjust (by trial and error) the font size and width of the listings so that no line shorter than my editor's number of columns (79 in my case) wraps.

Comment: Rather than an image of the code, you should add a small part of it so we can experiment with it (and not retype it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will fix the question. The solution that I found now is to use: basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize.